# Formal proof of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

> $$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) $$

How do I write a formal proof of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = c$ and let $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $\delta >0$ such that $$|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-c | < \epsilon$$
now note that $$|h| = |(a+h)-a|$$ and so
$$|h|< \delta \implies  |f(a+h)-c | < \epsilon$$
which shows that $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h) = c$. It follows that
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = c= \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h).$$

Comment: You don't really need to have two proofs here, in other words you proved that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = c, \lim_{h \to 0} f(a + h) = c$ then by equality we have $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h)$.

Comment: @DanZimm Right thanks, it's been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = L$ then for $h := x-a$

$$|f(a+h) - L |=|f(x) - L | < \epsilon$$

when

$$|h|=|a+h - a | = |x-a| < \delta$$.

Answer (score -1):

Pose $h=x-a$, then $x=a+h$ and when $x\to a$, there is $h\to 0$. Then,

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x-a\to 0}f(x-a+a)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$$