# Is there a flaw in this proof that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

I found 3 answers for a proof at [Formal proof of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895480/formal-proof-of-lim-x-to-afx-lim-h-to-0-fah).  The selected answer seemed more rigorous, but the 3rd answer (repeated here) seemed simpler.   Is the 3rd answer flawed?  In general, can you substitute limit variables such as changing $\lim_{x\to a}$ to $\lim_{h\to 0}$?
The third answer was: Pose h=x-a, then x=a+h, and when $x\to a$, there is $h\to 0$.  Then, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x-a\to 0}f(x-a+a)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$

This is not a dup of the referenced question because I asked if 3rd proof in original question was valid, and was that technique valid in general.

Comment: My question is different.  The existing question asked for a proof.  My question asks two separate questions: 1) Is the 3rd answer in the existing question a valid proof and 2) is the technique for substituting limit variables valid in general.  I already edited my question to explain the difference, but I apologize for being new with math.stackexchange so I have explained the difference in this comment.  I am not sure where to explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it if $h(x)$ is a continuous function. For example, you also have that $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(\cos(x))=\lim_{h\to1}f(h)$$ because $h(x)=\cos(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. The proof for this is quite similar to the one you posted in the question.