# proof lim x-a f(x)= lim x-0 f(x+a) ( duplicate)

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

i guess the proof here([Formal proof of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895480/formal-proof-of-lim-x-to-afx-lim-h-to-0-fah)) is something wrong, its too easy and i thought i couldnt change things like the one most voted

Comment: Why do you suppose it is wrong just because it is "too easy"?

Comment: how can I say: im a little bit scared about changing the letters, maybe this can generate a problem in domain for example , i really don't know if this will be a problem, but how im new in proofs like this, it seems that everything is too fragille

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the formal substitution $x\leftrightarrow a+h$,
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L\iff\forall\,\epsilon>0:\exists\,\delta>0:|x-a|<\epsilon\implies|f(x)-L|<\delta$$

is strictly equivalent to

$$\lim_{a+h\to a}f(a+h)=L\iff\forall\,\epsilon>0:\exists\,\delta>0:|a+h-a|<\epsilon\implies|f(a+h)-L|<\delta$$

or after simplification
$$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=L\iff\forall\,\epsilon>0:\exists\,\delta>0:|h|<\epsilon\implies|f(a+h)-L|<\delta.$$

Comment: so i can/may change letters  without no problem? i was afraid this could give me some problems in the domain

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa: no problem at all, $x$ and $a+h$ take the same values and there is a bijection between $x$ and $h$.

Comment: it was something like a translation in the x axis? Thank u so much for explaining me :D